# Confused about referencing layout during onCreate method

Tags: java, android

I'm a bit confused about behaviour of *this* and referencing layout in onCreate method.

I was creating a small application to experiment with android, it's purpose was to change background color of layout.

Here's a test piece of code that's bugging me and as far as I'm concerned it should work but does not:

```
private RelativeLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // nothing happens
}
```

However if I do it like this, it works:

```
private RelativeLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.colorLayout);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // color changes
}
```

What's the difference here?

Why doesn't the first code work properly?

Shouldn't *this* point to current layout?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In this case `this` is a reference to the current activity and its context, it isn't intended to point to the layout or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first way, you made a new RelativeLayout, but not added it to your view. There are two ways to fix this:

**First Way:**

Above onCreate(), declare your view:

```
RelativeLayout layout;
```

In your onCreate(), add this:

```
layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
setContentView(layout);
```

**Second Way:**

Above onCreate(), declare your view:

```
RelativeLayout layout;
```

In your onCreate(), add this:

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.colorLayout);
layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
mainLayout.addView(layout);
```

But if you did it like this, you will now have two RelativeLayout. So I recommend you to use your solution you posted normally in your question. That's simpler and better. This answer only fixes your first way that did not work, but you also really need to learn what I wrote.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thank you, I believe now it's clean to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // nothing happens
```

`layout` object of `RelativeLayout` is just created not added to Activity content layout.

to make it effect pass `layout` object to  `setContentView` as:

```
setContentView(layout);
```